# How to animate reversed icon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Found out a strange problem when I was creating a rotation animation for an Icon.

I use `RotationTransition` to animate `Icons.sync`. And I also use `Transform` because I need a mirrored version of the icon. The results is strange - it is not rotating, but moving by circular trajectory and then breaking. Without `Transform` everything is OK.

How it works now (new clicks on the button doesn't start animation, only page loading starts it):
[image]

How it works without `Transform` (as expexted)
[image]

The animated icon widget code:

```dart
class _AnimatedSyncIconState extends State<AnimatedSyncIcon>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController controller;
  late final Animation<double> rotateAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
    rotateAnimation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.linear);
    _animate();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(final AnimatedSyncIcon oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.isActive != oldWidget.isActive) _animate();
  }

  void _animate() {
    if (widget.isActive) {
      controller.repeat();
    } else {
      controller.reset();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return RotationTransition(
      turns: rotateAnimation,
      child: Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.rotationY(pi),
        child: const Icon(Icons.sync),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to make it work properly with the mirrored icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need one simple change, just transform your icon like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return RotationTransition(
      turns: rotateAnimation,
        child: Transform.scale(
        scaleX: -1,
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.sync, 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

now your icon will be mirrored and rotating correctly and you don't even need to import `dart:math` anymore

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to animate icon, you may adjust below example code according to your need. i hope it will help you.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedSyncIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimatedSyncIcon();

  @override
  State<AnimatedSyncIcon> createState() => _AnimatedSyncIconState();
}

class _AnimatedSyncIconState extends State<AnimatedSyncIcon>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller =
      AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2))
        ..repeat(reverse: true);

  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (_, child) {
            return Transform.rotate(
              angle: _controller.value * 2 * math.pi,
              child: child,
            );
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.sync),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the described problem, only rotates the icon in different directions.